# "Scroll back" on unfocus (blur) of contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable element that should presumably start with a relativly small width and then as you put content into it, it expands untill it reaches the maximum width, clipping the content.

I would like it to "scroll back" to the beginning much like a text box. I've tried setting the caret position to the start and it indeed works, but doesn't "scroll back". ***I've also tried setting the content to nothing (""), and then after 1ms back to what it was with the help of setTimeout, altough this is a very dirty solution :(***

I can't use a textbox for this is because I only want the content to be editable after a doubleclick. Could someone please help?

HTML:

```
<section contenteditable='true'>Edit me!</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:inline;
    white-space:nowrap;
    max-width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/varngjd3/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use .scrollLeft to set the scroll position of the overflow. I've using the 'onblur' attribute for your section to trigger when the section is no longer the focus, it passes `this` for our function to use instead of getting the element later:

```
<section contenteditable='true' onblur="resetOverflowPosition(this)">This should be long enough to mean that you can scroll forward and the script will scroll backwards</section>
```

Here we set `scrollLeft` to `0` to reset the current scroll of the section, you can use this function numerous times:

```
function resetOverflowPosition(element){
    element.scrollLeft = 0;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/np72zxo0/2/. Don't hesitate to comment if you need any more help.